# Usar sentencia Select para que me aparezcan varias columnas en una sola

Tags: mysql

Usando MySQL intento que al yo seleccionar por ejemplo el nombre el apellido 1 y el apellido 2 me aparezca todo en la misma columna con el nombre de Nombre completo.

He intentando resolverlo usando el lo siguiente pero al ejecutarlo los resultados se muestran a 0 o null.

`select nomem + ' - ' + 
    ape1em + ' - ' +
    ape2em 'Nombre completo'
    from empleados
    ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

saludos

usa la funcion CONCAT de mysql para concatenar tus campos

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp

ejemplo `SELECT CONCAT("SQL ", "Tutorial ", "is ", "fun!") AS ConcatenatedString;`

buen dia

Comment: Hay 2 problemas con `CONCAT` para lo que quiere el op. El primero es que si hay un `NULL`, todo el resultado será `NULL`. El segundo es que no hay un delimitador

Comment: Tienes toda la razón es mas efectivo concat_ws

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la función [`CONCAT_WS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' - ',nomem,ape1em,ape2em) NombreCompleto
FROM empleados;
```